# Durability of materials in ideal conditions

Tags: science-based, materials, time

How long can objects made of hard material last at room temperature in otherwise ideal conditions?

If left outdoors on Earth, over the course of millions of years, any material will be eroded by wind, rain, temperature fluctuations etc.

But what if you take an object of some hard ceramic like aluminum oxide, and keep it in an environment where the temperature is always an unvarying 15 Celsius, no wind ever blows, not a drop of rain ever falls, no force ever disturbs the object? Where nothing would deform it except for the sheer random migration of atoms? Suppose some handwavium were to keep these undisturbed conditions for trillions of years, would the object last that long?

Answer (score 4):

Dinosaur fossils are known to have lasted for a few hundred million years. The actual oldest fossils are for bacteria that lived half a billion years. Think of that ;)

If you wish to keep an object for millions of years, you could bury it in an exoplanet - or better yet, a rogue planet. Between the cold temperature and the emptiness of space, your object could last many billions of years.

Answer (score 4):

The object would last for a very long time indeed, for trillions of years. Ultimately there is some question over the stability of protons. The real answer is we can’t be sure, but it is possible that protons have a half life and would decay after 10^23 years.

http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Particles/proton.html

In which case the atoms would disintegrate in the “fullness of time”.

Comment: It may be worth referencing why the kilogram is no longer defined by the "reference kilogram", as that carefully-preserved cylinder of platinum and iridium lost 50 micrograms over 118 years.  How much of grandfather's axe can be lost before it is no longer the same object?